# Is there a way to insert dataframe into mysql using pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have this:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
host = "localhost"
port=3306
user = "db"
password='pass'
db='test'
charset='utf8mb4'
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
try:
    connection= pymysql.connect(host=host,port=port,user=user,password=passw,db=db,charset=charset,cursorclass=cursorclass)
    Executor=connection.cursor()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()
```

I tried using the pandas `to_sql()`, but it is replacing the values in the table with the latest one. I want to insert the values into the table using the Pandas, but I want to avoid the duplicate entries and if any then it should get passed.

Comment: I'm afraid pandas won't cover your conditions. Use custom library for Db manipulations

Comment: Do you have any example available that would help me?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to pickle the dataframe, and insert it into a table under a column of type `BLOB`.  If you go this way, you'd have to depickle the result returned by mysqld

EDIT:  I see what you are trying to do now.  Here is a possible solution.  Let me know if it works!

```py
# assume you have declared df and connection

records = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')

for record in records:
    sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ({0}) \
           VALUES ({1})".format(record.keys(), record.values())
    curs = connection.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute(sql)
        curs.close()
    except:
        break        #handle/research the error
```